# entity framework core multiple relation to same table complications

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

i've the following class

```
public class ReleatedProduct
{
    public int ReleatedProductId { get; set; }
    public int FirstProductId { get; set; }
    public Product FirstProduct { get; set; }
    public int SecondProductId { get; set; }
    //public Product SecondProduct { get; set; }
}
```

this relation should not exist if either the parties (product one of product two) are deleted, so i'm in a nutshell trying to cascade deleting on both

first thing i tried

```
builder.Entity<Product>()
        .HasMany<ReleatedProduct>(p => p.ReleatedProducts)
        .WithOne(rp => rp.FirstProduct)
        .HasForeignKey(rp => rp.FirstProductId)
        .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
        .HasForeignKey(rp => rp.SecondProductId)
        .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

but it failed and thrown an error that you can't have 2 releation on the same navigation property (p.ReleatedProducts, which is of type ReleatedProduct if this ain't obvious)

then i tried splitting this navigation property to two properties (one as a dummy

```
    builder.Entity<ReleatedProduct>()
        .HasOne(rp => rp.FirstProduct)
        .WithMany(p => p.ReleatedProductsFrom)
        .HasForeignKey(rp => rp.FirstProductId)
        .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    builder.Entity<ReleatedProduct>()
        .HasOne(rp => rp.SecondProduct)
        .WithMany(p => p.ReleatedProductsTo)
        .HasForeignKey(rp => rp.SecondProductId)
        .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

but it still failed miserably throwing an error that this may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

i tried using name conventions and nav property only, and it resulted in the same error

so any solution or work around ?

p.s. the constrain gets generated as intended (2 FKs for first and second products with the ondelete cascade) but the db would not accepting it throwing the second error "may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths"

Comment: First attempt is just incorrect configuration in EF. You cannot define 2 different FKs for single relationship.

Comment: The second attempt is is SqlServer limitation. Perhaps what you want to do (delete if either parent is deleted) will not be possible to do in SqlServer. Search for "may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths"